# Deploy rails app with ActionCable to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, actioncable

I created simple online chat using ROR and ActionCable.
And then try to deploy app to heroku.

But I have a strange error after deploy and app wont run.

Heroku build log:

```
   .........
   Bundle completed (0.70s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
   Could not detect rake tasks
   ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
   and using the production group of your Gemfile.
   rake aborted!
   TypeError: nil is not a symbol
   /tmp/build_5cc20a589923a15d8ef20f9d30e7babf/kokosko-chat-c869529/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/actioncable-98855fea634a/lib/action_cable.rb:29:in `module_function'
   /tmp/build_5cc20a589923a15d8ef20f9d30e7babf/kokosko-chat-c869529/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/actioncable-98855fea634a/lib/action_cable.rb:29:in `<module:ActionCable>'
   /tmp/build_5cc20a589923a15d8ef20f9d30e7babf/kokosko-chat-c869529/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/actioncable-98855fea634a/lib/action_cable.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
   .........
```

action_cable.rb from github:

```
  # Singleton instance of the server
  module_function def server       #line #29
    @server ||= ActionCable::Server::Base.new
  end
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'actioncable', github: 'rails/actioncable'
```

At local machine all work fine.
Any ideas?

Source, if it will help: https://github.com/kokosko/chat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you were running ruby 2.0 or lower. Rails 5.0 requires ruby 2.2.

The precise cause for this error message is that in previous versions of ruby

```
def foo
end
```

returns nil, whereas as of ruby 2.1, it will return `:foo`. The code you posted relies on this change.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I forgot set Ruby version in my Gemfile and Heroku use old 2.0.0 version, instead of 2.2.2 on localhost.